# Powershell parallel in function

Tags: powershell

Good afternoon.

I had the following question. In PowerShell, I have a function that goes insert to mssql database. I want it to work parallel. I wrote Workflow and run it like this:

```
workflow Run-Parallel_test{

parallel {
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
  }
}
```

but I ran into a problem that only 5 functions are launched at the same time, apparently there is a limitation, how can I get around it? Or is there a way to run the same function on Powershell in parallel for a given number of times?

Comment: You _can_ configure a higher threshold for concurrent executions in workflows, but it might be a good idea to examine whether workflows are really the right tool for the job - what is your motivation for trying to execute multiple insert queries in parallel?

Comment: this is necessary for a stress test of the server when there will be a large number of simultaneous connections

Comment: Maybe use a dedicated [stress tool](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/04/free-sql-server-load-testing-tools/) - which is by far, not trivial to get realistic - instead?